# Form in card body not visible with NativeBase

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, native-base

I try using below code (a `Form` inside a `Card` component)

```
<Card>
   <CardItem header style={{ backgroundColor: 'lightgray' }}>
   <Right>
      <Text>This is Right align text </Text>
   </Right>
   <Badge primary>
      <Text>step 1</Text>
   </Badge>
   </CardItem>
   <CardItem>
      <Body>
         <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>{this.state.error}</Text>
         <Form style={{alignSelf: 'stretch'}}>
         <Item>
            <Label>number:</Label>
            <Input keyboardType="numeric"/>
         </Item>
         <Item>
            <Label>date:</Label>
            <Input />
         </Item>
         <Item>
            <Label>number 2:</Label>
            <Input keyboardType="numeric"/>
         </Item>
         <Item>
            <Label>date 2:</Label>
            <Input />
         </Item>
         <Button success block
            >
            <Text>submit</Text>
            <Icon name='check' size={20} color="#FFFFFF"/>
         </Button>
         </Form>
      </Body>
   </CardItem>
</Card>
```

But in my device Nexus 7 Tab with android 5 footer not visible.
Do you have any suggestion for find the issue and fix it?
I'm using NativeBase `2.0.12` and React-Native `0.42.0`.

[image: screenshot_2017-03-22-12-00-35]

I think it's maybe related to this issue: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/668

**Try 1:** 
I change my code a little and add `style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}` for `CardItem` that not appear and find it on the outer card component. This is my new code:

```
<Card>
   <CardItem header style={{ backgroundColor: 'lightgray' }}>
   <Right>
      <Text>This is Right align text </Text>
   </Right>
   <Badge primary>
      <Text>step 1</Text>
   </Badge>
   </CardItem>
   <CardItem style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
   <Body>
      <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>{this.state.error}</Text>
      <Form style={{alignSelf: 'stretch'}}>
      <Item>
         <Label>number:</Label>
         <Input keyboardType="numeric"/>
      </Item>
      <Item>
         <Label>date:</Label>
         <Input />
      </Item>
      <Item>
         <Label>number 2:</Label>
         <Input keyboardType="numeric"/>
      </Item>
      <Item>
         <Label>date 2:</Label>
         <Input />
      </Item>
      <Button success block
         >
         <Text>submit</Text>
         <Icon name='check' size={20} color="#FFFFFF"/>
      </Button>
      </Form>
   </Body>
   </CardItem>
</Card>
```

And this is new screenshot:
[image: screenshot_2017-03-22-18-27-22]

When I remove `Form` component from `CardItem` it's render successfully like below:

```
<Card>
   <CardItem header style={{ backgroundColor: 'lightgray' }}>
   <Right>
      <Text>This is Right align text </Text>
   </Right>
   <Badge primary>
      <Text>step 1</Text>
   </Badge>
   </CardItem>
   <CardItem style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
   <Body>
      <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>{this.state.error}</Text>
   </Body>
   </CardItem>
</Card>
```

[image: screenshot_2017-03-22-18-32-42]

Why we can't use `Form` inside `CardItem`? Is it an undocumented limitation of `Card` component?

Comment: replace ```Card``` with ```View``` from react-native

Answer (score 1):

Your Card Component is having flex direction column property by default, change it to row so that the form can be visible to you below your first card.

`

```
<Card style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
    <CardItem header style={{ backgroundColor: 'lightgray' }}>
        <Right>
            <Text>This is Right align text </Text>
        </Right>
        <Badge primary>
            <Text>step 1</Text>
        </Badge>
    </CardItem>
    <CardItem style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
        <Body>
            <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>{this.state.error}</Text>
            <Form style={{ alignSelf: 'stretch' }}>
                <Item>
                    <Label>number:</Label>
                    <Input keyboardType="numeric" />
                </Item>
                <Item>
                    <Label>date:</Label>
                    <Input />
                </Item>
                <Item>
                    <Label>number 2:</Label>
                    <Input keyboardType="numeric" />
                </Item>
                <Item>
                    <Label>date 2:</Label>
                    <Input />
                </Item>
                <Button success block
                >
                    <Text>submit</Text>
                    <Icon name='check' size={20} color="#FFFFFF" />
                </Button>
            </Form>
        </Body>
    </CardItem>
</Card>
```

`